# input:valid triggered even if it isn't valid

Tags: css

I have made a material design form but input:valid doesn't work the way it should. so the label should be in the form but if :focus or if :valid the label should move up and change the font size

```
.link-input input:focus ~ label, 
.link-input input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5264AE; }
```

if i delete the

> .link-input input:valid ~ label

from the above syntax on :focus works just right.

here is the example on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/onjpeo7g/1/

Comment: Ehm... the input in the fiddle can't be invalid. It has no attributes like `required` and no type that can be used to determine what is valid content and what isn't.

Comment: Thank you, i added "required" attribute and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the input sees an empty field as valid input.

So change your selector from:

```
body .page .content .generator-box .link-input input:focus ~ label,
body .page .content .generator-box .link-input input:valid ~ label
```

To:

```
body .page .content .generator-box .link-input input:focus ~ label,
body .page .content .generator-box .link-input input:valid:not(:empty) ~ label
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/onjpeo7g/2/)